# Binding different event listeners in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

## What I want

I have a Vue component. Inside the component I'm rendering list of actions using `v-for`. Each action should have a `@click` event handler that executes it's corresponding action (method of the component)

I do not know how to declare the actions in my `data()` and how to bind the actions to a `@click`

## Code

**template**

```html
        <v-menu
          v-for="item in items"
          v-else
          :key="item"
          top
          rounded
        >
          <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn
              v-bind="attrs"
              icon
              class="mt-3"
              v-on="on"
            >
              <v-icon>
                mdi-dots-vertical
              </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item
              link
            >
              <v-list-item-title @click="???(todo)"> //　I wont　item.action...
                <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                {{ item.title }}
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
      </v-menu>
```

**script**

```js
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        { title: 'edit', icon: 'mdi-pencil', action: ??? }, // => action: toEdit(todo)
        { title: 'delete', icon: 'mdi-delete', action: ??? } // => action: remove(todo)
      ]
    },

  methods: {
    toEdit (todo) {
      this.selectedTodo = todo
      this.itemText = todo.text
      this.$store.commit('todos/toggle', todo)
    },
    removeTodo (todo) {
      this.$store.commit('todos/remove', todo)
    }
   }
  }
```

## What I tried myself

1. Changed `item.action`
   **script**

```js
data () {
    return {
      items: [
        { title: 'edit', icon: 'mdi-pencil', action: `${this.toEdit}` },
        { title: 'delete', icon: 'mdi-delete', action: `${this.removeTodo}` }
      ]
}
// handler.apply is not a function
```

2. Changed `items.action` to add `triggerClick` methods
   **template**

```html
...
     <v-list-item-title @click="triggerClick(item.action, todo)"> // @click="item.action" => @click="triggerClick(item.action, todo)"
...
```

**script**

```js
  data () {
    return {
      itemText: '',
      selectedTodo: [],
      items: [
        { title: 'edit', icon: 'mdi-pencil', action: 'edit' }, //`${this.toEdit}` => edit
        { title: 'delete', icon: 'mdi-delete', action: 'remove' } // `${this.removeTodo}` => 'remove'
      ]

    }
  },
methods: {

...

//add
    triggerClick (action, todo) {
      if (action === 'edit') {
        this.toEdit(todo)
      } else if (action === 'remove') {
        this.removeTodo(todo)
      }
    }

// Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define your actions as strings - each string should correspond to a method name you want execute on click

```js
{ text: 'edit text', icon: 'mdi-pencil', action: 'toEdit' }, 
{ text: 'delete text', icon: 'mdi-delete', action: 'removeTodo' }
```

2. Create a method that receives 2 parameters - one is action (method name) and other is the todo item

```js
methods: {
  callTodoAction(action, todo) {
    this[action](todo);
  }
}
```

3. Use it in the template

```html
<v-list-item-title @click="callTodoAction(item.action, todo)">
```

4. Learn how and why the `callTodoAction` above works: [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Wow! I didn't know there was such a great way. Thank you very much. I am grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<v-list-item-title @click="triggerClick(item)"> 
  <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
  {{ item.title }}
</v-list-item-title>

// need text properties
// used this.itemText = todo.text
// not title
items:[
  { text: 'edit text', icon: 'mdi-pencil', action: 'edit' }, 
  { text: 'delete text', icon: 'mdi-delete', action: 'remove' }
]

triggerClick(todo){
  const { action } = tode
  action === 'edit' && this.toEdit(todo)
  action === 'remove' && this.removeTodo(todo)
}
```